# Inflation of Reputation

Tags: discussion

How does stack exchange identify if someone is inflating his/her own reputations?

On the other day, my other account was been banned for a week because my friend gave me a vote up on my all questions and answers.

Isnt it legal?

Comment: why is this question getting downvotes?

Comment: Probably because this is entirely unrelated to serverfault other than the same company runs this site.  It would be appropriate in meta (which I assume it'll be migrated to shortly).

Comment: It's entirely *legal*, but it's probably against the StackOverflow rules and terms.

Comment: Further reading (for your friend): [How to vote on friends / colleagues ' questions (or answers)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138517/241919)

Comment: If you really want to, you can trick the system. But doing that correctly, with close-to-zero risk does not worth the price. Note, SE, while it is funny, it is also a psychological hack. If you trick the system - with a lot of work - to get to a high rep easily, then you violate its written rules, but you can not do it without producing also worthy content. With this, you still do what the creators of the SE do want from you.

Answer (score 4):

No, its against their CoC.

The complete how its detected is keep in secret, but for sure we know that for one account that target another account for upvoting or downvoting will get tagged by the system. Same with the localisation.

The goal of such action from SE is to prevent voting fraud. As if everyone could be able to do that the point system will loose it’s usefulness, it would be unbalanced and would mean nothing in the long term.

Imaging too if someone hate you and start downvoting everything from you, the system prevent such bulk action too.

See that post for more information; https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/12/23/vote-fraud-and-you/